# Error "from imp import new_module ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'" on Debugger Launch Profile

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm using Microsoft's [Python and Django tutorial in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_create-a-debugger-launch-profile), but when I try to create a debugger launch profile, I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/andres/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_utils.py", line 32, in save_main_module
    from imp import new_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
```

Also, there's an error message that appears on my "manage.py" file:

```
Exception has occurred: SystemExit
1
  File "/Users/andres/Documents/hello_django/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/andres/Documents/hello_django/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
SystemExit: 1
```

According to a Google search, seems that the profile is trying to use the "imp" library, which has been deprecated since Python 3.4 and is currently replaced with import lib. However, I have confirmed that my environment is using Python 3.12.1 and I can't identify where this library is being called.

I'll really appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you have selected wrong python env. Can you check on right bottom corner of vscode and make sure the indented python is selected?

Comment: @VinitaSonakiya Thanks for your reply! I have confirmed that I'm using the right python env, but the problem persists.

Comment: Try to update your debugger by command `pip install --upgrade debugpy`.

Comment: Hi I'm having the same error but running a Flask application. I can run the script without any errors but as soon as I start using the debugger with a launch.json file the script wiill raise an Exception and the terminal prompts "from imp import new_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'"

Upgrading debugpy did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I went down this rabbit hole and figured out a workaround:
In the "pydev_utils.py" I imported the "types" module, commented "from imp import new_module" in the function "save_main_module" out and replaced the code

```
m = new_module('__main__')
```

with

```
m = types.ModuleType('__main__')
```

See the picture below.

[image: Screenshot of solution]

Maybe this can fix your issue as well.

Used reference: https://github.com/construct/construct/issues/810